# Finding points that satisfy a tangent plane with equal $x$ and $y$ coefficients

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My entire Calculus III high school class (including the teacher) have been struggling on this problem and we really need some help.

> Find all points of the surface given by
>
> $x^3 + 3yx^2 + 6yz - 3z^2 = 7$
>
> where the tangent plane has an equation of the form $Ax + Ay = B$, for
> some constants $A$ and $B$

Currently, we've tried to work through the problem like so:

> Implicitly derive  $x^3 + 3yx^2 + 6yz - 3z^2 = 7$ to recieve:
>
> $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{3x^2+6xy}{6z-6y}$
>
> $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{3x^2+6z}{6z-6y}$
>
> We were under the assumption that in the tangent plane formula, $z -
>  c$ would be $0$, as there is no $z$ after the $B$ coefficient in the
> given equation
>
> This gave us a final tangent plane equation of:
>
> $\displaystyle 0 = \frac{3a^2x+6abx-3a^3-6a^2b+3a^2y+6cy-3a^2b-6cb}{6c-6b}$
>
> $\displaystyle \frac{3a^3+9a^2b+6cb}{6c-6b} = \left(\frac{3a^2+6ab}{6c-6b}\right)x + \left(\frac{3a^2+6c}{6c-6b}\right)y$
>
> (where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the $x$, $y$, and $z$ values at the
> points we're solving for)
>
> Since the coefficients for $x$ and $y$ are the same, we then set
>
> $\displaystyle\frac{3a^2+6ab}{6c-6b} = \frac{3a^2+6c}{6c-6b}$
>
> This told us $ab = c$, which we used to reformat the original equation
> given into
>
> $a^3 + 3a^2b+6b^2a-3a^2b^2=7$
>
> Which we thought would be almost there.

Our class was under the belief that another equation would be needed to solve for $a$ and $b$ in a system, which would then give us the values of $A$ and $B$ and allow us to solve the question.

Some of the class is still thinking along this line of reasoning, and others think we've gone down a completely incorrect path towards the solution, but none of us have solved it and just a point in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Yes, edit your question to include your work. I can’t guess where you ran into difficulties. I find three points.

Comment: What a way to make it too hard! This is a level surface of $f(x,y,z)$. What should be the automatic approach to find a *normal vector* to the surface? (Note that your approach deals at best only with points where the surface is a graph over the $xy$-plane,)

Comment: Oh, silly of me not to have made a stronger comment. The equation you were given of the tangent plane says specifically that the tangent plane is *vertical*, and so, in particular, $z$ is *not* locally given as a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You are right, although your derivation is flawed, that $c=ab$. But what you’re missing is that $b=c$ — i.e., the denominators of your fractions must be $0$. You almost always want to (must) use the gradient vector of $f$.

Comment: Thank you. I used the gradient of $f$ this time and got two working points (1,-2,-2) and (1,1,1)

Can you confirm if these are the right points? I'm also wondering if I'm missing any points as well.

Comment: You're missing one point, I believe. There's another solution of the equations $b=c$ and $c=ab$. Students often make a mistake of missing solutions when they cancel without considering other possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I approached this question the wrong way.

Instead, start with the partial derivatives of $f(x,y,z) = x^3+3yx^2+6yz−3z^2-7$

> $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 3x^2 + 6xy$
>
> $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 3x^2 + 6z$
>
> $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 6y - 6z$

Note that $Ax + Ay = B$, which means that the tangent plane is vertical and the $z$ component of the gradient vector must equal $0$ meaning

> $0 = 6y - 6z$
>
> $6z = 6y$
>
> $z = y$

Also, note that because $Ax + Ay = B$, the $x$ and $y$ components of the gradient vector must be equal to each other

> $3x^2 + 6xy = 3x^2 + 6z$
>
> $6xy = 6z$
>
> $xy = z$ which means $y$ and $z$ could both equal $0$ *or* $x = 1$

From here, we can begin solving for some points, beginning with the one where $y$ and $z$ are zero.

> $x^3 + 3(0)x^2 + 6(0)(0) - 3(0)^2 = 7$
>
> $x^3 = 7$
>
> $x = \sqrt[3]{7}$ and we've found one point $(\sqrt[3]{7}, 0, 0)$

Now, to solve for the points where $x = 1$

> $(1)^3 + 3y(1)^2 + 6yz − 3y^2 = 7$
>
> $3y^2 + 3y - 6 = 0$
>
> $(y-1)(y+2) = 0$
>
> $y = 1$ *or* $y = -2$ so we've found the final points $(1,1,1)$ and
> $(1,-2,-2)$

Final points are $(\sqrt[3]{7}, 0, 0)$, $(1,1,1)$, and $(1,-2,-2)$

Comment: Well done! And well written!